# cocos2d-x FIXED_WIDTH isn't working

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.x

I have a 700x1280 image and my design resolution is 700x1280.
I am not providing separate assets for each device that I target rather i will use one Resource which contains all my assets.

The problem:

When I set my design resolution I pass a ResolutionPolicy::FIXED_WIDTH meaning from what I understand it will scale the width with no bordering but the height may be bordered. But all I see is a fixed width but the height of the image goes out of the screen i.e it's not making the height fit in the screen like FIXED_WIDTH is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED_WIDTH only promises to keep the width using the full physical width of the screen but doesn't promise that the height will stay the same i.e it may go out of the screen. For portrait mode FIXED_HEIGHT is the way to go because your height on any device is definitely bigger than that of the width so by using FIXED_HEIGHT the width will never go out of screen, it's a bummer but that's what you have to do!